# Return rotated rectangle in Java

Tags: java, collision-detection, rectangles

I'm using Java Rectangles in my game in order to check collision between objects (using the `intersects()` method). As far as I know, this cannot be done if one of the objects is rotated.

Say, for example, one of the objects in the game is rotated 65°. How would I go about checking collision on this object? Is there a way I can add rotation to its Rectangle? If not, is there a way I can check collision without using Rectangles (using e.g. pixel colors)?

Comment: Have you tried using pencil and paper, drawing two rectangles, one rotated an one not, and coming up with an  algorithm?  Then translate that into your own `intersects` method. That is how most problems like this would be solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java collision detection between two Shape objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690846/java-collision-detection-between-two-shape-objects)

Comment: I have voted this as a duplicate for shape rotation, because if you use Java Shapes (of which Rectangles are a special case), you have built-in collision detection, regardless of rotation.

Comment: @gpash you need segment intersection if you want to do it right: picture two elongated rectangles making an X, where no point of either rectangle is inside the other. Note that you need segments, and line intersection is not enough: picture those same segments, forming a T where the top does not touch the stem.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should provide more information about your project, even by showing us a few lines of code. Anyway, if you are working with Cartesian plane, one way to rotate a point is this:

```
    public Point ruota(double alpha, Point r){
      double qx = r.x + (x - r.x) * Math.cos(alpha) - (y - r.y)* Math.sin(alpha);
      double qy = r.y + (x - r.x) * Math.sin(alpha) + (y - r.y)* Math.cos(alpha);
      return new Point(qx, qy);
    }
```

Comment: I haven't worked with Points before, so just as an example - would this create a rectangle that is rotated 45°?

Rectangle r = new Rectangle(new Point(100, 100));
r.add(new Point(150, 50));
r.add(new Point(200,100));
r.add(new Point(150, 150));

Comment: A rotation requires a center of rotation. You are using r as a center there, and your code is missing arguments `x` and `y`, the coordinates for the point you are rotating.

Comment: @tucuxi If you are referring to my code, r is an instance of Point class: x and y do not need to be defined in this method.

Comment: Ah. There is a [Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) class already in `java.awt`, and I thought you were using it instead of writing your own.